# Angular 2 rc3 - unresolved dependencies

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Im using packages.json from official Angular2 site, the quick start. Yesterday it was working fine, today npm cant resolve dependecies. I get error:

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.3 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.3 wants @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.3
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.3 wants @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.3
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/forms@0.1.1 wants @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.3
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.3 wants @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.3
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.3 wants @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.3
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.3 wants @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.3
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/router@3.0.0-alpha.7 wants @angular/core@^2.0.0-rc.2
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/router-deprecated@2.0.0-rc.2 wants @angular/core@^2.0.0-rc
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/upgrade@2.0.0-rc.3 wants @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.3
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.12 wants @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.2
```

My npm-debug: http://q.i-systems.pl/file/3dd29e55.zip

Comment: It seems removing node_module dir and then run install works ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens when you update some packages and leave some hanging, that's what angular just did in **`RC.3`**.

---

So instead of fixing who needs what,

- I deleted `node_modules`
- copied `package.json` from QuickStart, added my extras
- ran `npm install`

*npm is happy again.*

Answer (score 5):

Upgrade npm worked for me:

```
npm install npm -g
```

Then delete node_modules and

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of mismatch of package version required.Inside quickstart folder there is file called package.json. This package.json looks like this

```
 {
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation,supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
  "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
  "docker-build": "docker build -t ng2-quickstart .",
  "docker": "npm run docker-build && docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 ng2-quickstart",
  "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update",
  "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server\" \"protractor    protractor.config.js\"",
  "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
  "lite": "lite-server",
  "postinstall": "typings install",
  "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
  "tsc": "tsc",
  "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
  "typings": "typings",
  "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update"
},
 "keywords": [],
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
      "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/forms": "0.1.0",
"@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/router":  "3.0.0-alpha.7",
"@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.2",

"systemjs": "0.19.27",
"core-js": "^2.4.0",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"zone.js": "^0.6.12",

"angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.12",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
},
"devDependencies": {
"concurrently": "^2.0.0",
"lite-server": "^2.2.0",
"typescript": "^1.8.10",
"typings": "^1.0.4",

"canonical-path": "0.0.2",
"http-server": "^0.9.0",
"tslint": "^3.7.4",
"lodash": "^4.11.1",
"jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
"karma": "^0.13.22",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
"karma-cli": "^0.1.2",
"karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
"protractor": "^3.3.0",
"rimraf": "^2.5.2"
},
"repository": {}
}
```

Now if look inside dependency section we see something like this

```
  dependencies": {
      "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/forms": "0.1.0",
"@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/router":  "3.0.0-alpha.7",
"@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
}
```

This is where we are specifying which packages we need along with its version. If want to use higher version of packages , use ^ in version number.Following will set dependency to rc.2 or higher

```
dependencies": {
"@angular/common":  "^2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/core":  "^2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/forms": "^0.1.0",
"@angular/http":  "^2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/platform-browser":  "^2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "^2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/router":  "^3.0.0-alpha.7",
"@angular/router-deprecated":  "^2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/upgrade":  "^2.0.0-rc.2"
}
```

Now go to shell and run command

```
 npm cache clean -f
 npm update -g
```

This will update your packages to higher version if available.